# How do I unmute the microphone on my Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am trying to call a friend with Google Voice on my Chromebook. However, my friend can't hear me because my microphone is muted.

Toggling the microphone icon via the Google Voice interface in Gmail chat does nothing. How do I unmute the microphone on my Chromebook?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Near the 'on/off' button on the top right section of the keyboard you will see three buttons:

- Increase volume
- Decrease volume
- Mute

Make sure you click on the 'increase volume' then if your mic volume is still low - try to connect a combo mic and headphone (TTRS). It will boost your mic volume.

Comment: Thanks, but how to I alter the volume of my microphone? He's the one who can't hear me.

Comment: I've just updated the answer - I hope it will work for you.

Comment: so the answer is to plug in a combo mic and headphone? how does this provide a solution to the question?